# JavaScript or jQuery browser back button click detector

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button

Could someone please share experience / code how we can detect the browser back button click (for any type of browsers)?

We need to cater all browser that doesn't support HTML5

Comment: You're looking for the HTML5 history API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect back button click in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: It is great that it is not working most of the time, because every site would abuse it.

Answer (score 68):

The 'popstate' event only works when you push something before. So you have to do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      alert('Back button was pressed.');
    });

  }
});
```

For browser backward compatibility I recommend: [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Comment: this does not distinguish between back or forward button, just popstate, wich can be both

Comment: Your code runs perfectly in desktop browser.But in mobile browser its not working properly

Comment: But alert fire on backword and forward both, how can i detect only back click

Comment: "The 'popstate' event only works when you push something before." This is GOLDEN! There are many examples out there, but the most important bit is this exact quote!

Comment: The code as is only works once for a given page. If you add another   
   "window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');"            after the alert, it keeps stopping the user from using the back button....hehe

Answer (score 15):

In javascript, navigation type 2 means browser's back or forward button clicked and the browser is actually taking content from cache.

```
if(performance.navigation.type == 2) {
    //Do your code here
}
```

Comment: Unless the page headers contained "no-store" or "must-revalidate"

Comment: This no longer works. perfermance.navigation.type just gives a value of 0 and has been deprecated and its alternative is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thank you Hasan, It worked and That was exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

there are a lot of ways how you can detect if user has clicked on the Back button. But everything depends on what your needs. Try to explore links below, they should help you.

Detect if user pressed "Back" button on current page:

- [Is there a way using Jquery to detect the back button being pressed cross browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462511/is-there-a-way-using-jquery-to-detect-the-back-button-being-pressed-cross-browse)
- [detect back button click in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser)

Detect if current page is visited after pressing "Back" button on previous("Forward") page:

- [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)
- [trigger event on browser back button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827411/trigger-event-on-browser-back-button-click)

Answer (score 9):

Found this to work well cross browser and mobile [back_button_override.js](https://gist.github.com/w33tmaricich/7009931) .

(Added a timer for safari 5.0)

```
// managage back button click (and backspace)
var count = 0; // needed for safari
window.onload = function () { 
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") { 
        history.pushState("back", null, null);          
        window.onpopstate = function () { 
            history.pushState('back', null, null);              
            if(count == 1){window.location = 'your url';}
         }; 
     }
 }  
setTimeout(function(){count = 1;},200);
```

Comment: Works like a charm on Firefox, but for some reason it doesn't always work on Chrome :/. Any suggestions on how to improve it to work on Chrome?

Answer (score 6):

In case of HTML5 this will do the trick

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
   alert("clicked back button");
}; history.pushState({}, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awesome plugin

https://github.com/ianrogren/jquery-backDetect

All you need to do is to write this code

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('body').backDetect(function(){
      // Callback function
      alert("Look forward to the future, not the past!");
    });
  });
```

Best

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using jQuery `.load()` to update DIVs in a SPA *(single page [web] app)* .

Being new to working with `$(window).on('hashchange', ..)` event listener , this one proved challenging and took a bit to hack on.  Thanks to reading a lot of answers and trying different variations,  finally figured out how to make it work in the following manner.  Far as I can tell, it is looking stable so far.

> In summary - there is the variable `globalCurrentHash` that should be set each time you load a view.
>
> Then when `$(window).on('hashchange', ..)` event listener runs, it checks the following:
>
> - If `location.hash` has the same value, it means *Going Forward*
> - If `location.hash` has different value, it means *Going Back*

I realize using global vars isn't the most elegant solution, but doing things OO in JS seems tricky to me so far.  Suggestions for improvement/refinement certainly appreciated

---

**Set Up:**

1. Define a global var :

```
    var globalCurrentHash = null;
```

2. When calling `.load()` to update the DIV, update the global var as well :

   ```
   function loadMenuSelection(hrefVal) {
     $('#layout_main').load(nextView);
     globalCurrentHash = hrefVal;
   }
   ```
3. On page ready, set up the listener to check the global var to see if Back Button is being pressed:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
         console.log( 'location.hash: ' + location.hash );
         console.log( 'globalCurrentHash: ' + globalCurrentHash );

         if (location.hash == globalCurrentHash) {
             console.log( 'Going fwd' );
         }
         else {

             console.log( 'Going Back' );
             loadMenuSelection(location.hash);
         }
       });

   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the HTML5 History API. The event is called `'popstate'`

Comment: We need to cater all browser that doesn't support HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Disable the url button by following function

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
        history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
            // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
        };
    }
    else {
        var ignoreHashChange = true;
        window.onhashchange = function () {
            if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                ignoreHashChange = true;
                window.location.hash = Math.random();
                // Detect and redirect change here
                // Works in older FF and IE9
                // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
                // delimiter on the end of the URL
            }
            else {
                ignoreHashChange = false;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hasan Badshah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5795364/hasan-badshah)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033622/7573223) worked for me, but the method is slated to be deprecated and may be problematic for others going forward.  Following the MDN web docs on alternative methods, I landed here: [PerformanceNavigationTiming.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type)

```
if (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === 'back_forward') {
  // back or forward button functionality
}
```

This doesn't directly solve for back button over the forward button, but was good enough for what I needed. In the docs they detail the available event data that may be helpful with solving your specific needs:

```
function print_nav_timing_data() {
  // Use getEntriesByType() to just get the "navigation" events
  var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

  for (var i=0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
    console.log("= Navigation entry[" + i + "]");
    var p = perfEntries[i];
    // dom Properties
    console.log("DOM content loaded = " + (p.domContentLoadedEventEnd - 
    p.domContentLoadedEventStart));
    console.log("DOM complete = " + p.domComplete);
    console.log("DOM interactive = " + p.interactive);

    // document load and unload time
    console.log("document load = " + (p.loadEventEnd - p.loadEventStart));
    console.log("document unload = " + (p.unloadEventEnd - 
    p.unloadEventStart));

    // other properties
    console.log("type = " + p.type);
    console.log("redirectCount = " + p.redirectCount);
  }
}
```

According to the Docs at the time of this post it is still in a working draft state and is not supported in IE or Safari, but that may change by the time it is finished.  Check the Docs for updates.

Answer (score -2):

suppose you have a button:

```
<button onclick="backBtn();">Back...</button>
```

Here the code of the backBtn method:

```
  function backBtn(){
                    parent.history.back();
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: I do not see why @senior got down votes?? This does work! If there are something i should know please let me know. ..

Comment: @Ingus Probably because this has nothing to do with the back navigation button of the browser itself. This is for creating a custom back button on your page.

Comment: This is not the back button.