# jQuery Mobile: remove elements from another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, single-page-application

For multiple page single html type application, is it possible to remove an element in previous page from an current active page so that when user clicks on a back button,
it will show updated page? I have tried something similar like below but it does not seem to work.

Thanks

ex)

```
<script>
   function somecallback_in_page1() {
      $("#page2").find("#foo").remove();
   }
</script>
<!-- current page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
   <div id="foo">bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both pages are in the DOM it is no problem:

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/AJ8mg/)**

Given these 2 pages:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My page 1</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn">Go to page 2</a>
        <div id="removeMe">
            this will be removed via a button click while you are on page 2            
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>  

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My page 2</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <button id="btnRemove">Remove Element from Page 1</button>
        <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn">Go back to page 1</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Navigate to page 2, click the remove element button, then navigate back to page 1.

The script is

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page2", function(){
    $("#btnRemove").on("click", function(){
        $("#removeMe").remove();
    });
});
```

Btw, it is good practice to make sure your DOM element IDs are unique across all pages; otherwise, you can run into confusing selector issues later.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just had a bug in my selector.

Comment: @ljustin, you are welcome. You also need to wait until the DOM is ready before executing your script...

Answer (score 0):

I have never used jquery to detect whether the back button is clicked but there are some good links on here. Check this post out:

[JavaScript or jQuery browser back button click detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/js-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector)

Once detected you could use jquery to hide the panel like this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
   $("#foo").hide();
});
</script>
```