# Handle Dialog Close event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My post submits the form and displays the dialog after it successfully submits everything. I am curious as how to change the event when this dialog is closed out by the X in the top corner to close something else as well such as another dialog.

```
$.post("test.php", $("#payment-form").serialize(),function(){ 
   $.mobile.changePage('#successfulPurchase');
});
```

I want to do

```
$("#subscribePage").dialog('close');
```

when the successfulPurchase dialog is closed out

Comment: Have you searched on jquery-mobile api to see which event you've got?

Comment: The popup has an afterclose event: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afterclose

Comment: So you think I should change my dialog to a popup and just use that? Because that sounds way easier

Comment: @pschemm031, it is not 100% clear from your question what you are trying to do. The popup widget is generally the way to go; however, jQM only allows one at a time to be open. So if you need 2 open at the same time, popup will not work. For that you might want to look at SimpleDialog2: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/

Comment: I have a dialog open which has a payment form. When submitted and successful, I need a thank you message to come up in a popup or dialog.But when the user closes out the thank you message I need both the new message to close along with the form dialog.

Comment: @pschemm031, if you use a popup for both, you would have to close the payment popup and then show the thank you popup. Note that jQM dialogs are deprecated and will go away in v1.5. SimpleDialog2 supports chained popups, see this article I wrote: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/. you can handle the close with the callbackClose option.

Comment: to close dialog `$.mobile.back()` or change page. Dialog emits `pagecontainerhide` when it's closed.

Comment: I have $.mobile.changePage to the success dialog, but the problem is when the user closes that out with the X it brings them back to the form that was submitted, when I need the dialog to close as well. So the user is back to the main page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26983272/1771795 just change `data.prevPage[0].id` to `data.prevPage.hasClass("ui-dialog")` and of course `#mainScreen` to `#your homepage id`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect a user when a dialog is close, use `pagecontainerbeforechange` event to alter `toPage` with a new target page. To determine whether the navigation direction is *back*, check value of `options.direction`. `prevPage` is a jQuery object of previous page/dialog.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if ( typeof data.toPage == "string" && data.options.direction == "back" && data.prevPage.hasClass("ui-dialog") ) {
        data.toPage = "#homepage"; /* redirect to homepage */
    }
});
```