# How to find out if the history back/forward was triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history

I'm using ajax to simulate a menu. All is fine but the **back** and **forward** buttons are not perfectly working.

So the code is:

```
$('#sdt_menu a').on('click', function (e) {
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    e.preventDefault();
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        document.url = event.state.url;
        loadSpecificPage(window.location.pathname);
    };
    pushingState(href);
})
```

`window.onpopstate` looks for changes in the history.
`pushingState` just pushes the new page to the history.

With this the menu items are correctly loaded into the browser history. But when I hit the back button for instance, the `window.onpopstate` as well as my `pushingState` function is triggered. So let's say I'm on page 1 and now load page 2. When I hit the back button now in the browser, I correctly go back to page 1 but I reload page 1 and go to it. So at the end I was not going back correctly. So the `pushingState` function shall not be triggered, then it should work properly. I at least just replaced the current page with the last in the current way.

**Summary**: the `window.onpopstate` is working properly. But the `pushingState` function shall not be triggered when hitting the browser back/forward button.

So my idea was to create an if statement that checks if one of the buttons was clicked. But I did not find something like that. Here some links that did not work for me: [detect back button click in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser) and [JavaScript or jQuery browser back button click detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/js-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector)

Maybe I'm thinking too hard into this direction and it's even easier somehow?

### Added pushingState function

```
function pushingState(href){
    if (href == "/about" || href == "/about/") {
        history.pushState('About', 'about', href);
    }
    if (href == "/creator" || href == "/creator/") {
        history.pushState('Creator', 'creator', href);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you right, first of all there is not such method pushingState but instead pushState which takes 3 parameters: state object , title , url. try to read this article from mdn:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: I know, I leaved it away for simplyfication but now added at the end. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm right now using this block of code. It's a little bit different from the original idea, and still not the perfect solution, but at least better and the back and forward buttons are working:

```
$('#sdt_menu a').on('click', function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(href, '', href);
    e.preventDefault();
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        if (event.state != null){
            document.url = event.state.url;
            pushingState(event.state);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The recent way to check (available in many browsers, but already deprecated), if the user has used the "back/forward" button, one can check for

```js
performance.navigation.type === 2
```

Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type

The most recent approach is (only available in more modern browsers), to check for

```js
performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward"
```

Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type