# How to get back the properties set to text box when page is loaded back by pressing back button in browser?

Tags: jquery

I have set the attribute of a text box to this  after an event

$("#txtTitleName").attr("disabled", "disabled");

After proceeding to next page if user comes back by pressing back button,this property disappears.

What is the solution to this,I am using MVC 5

Comment: you need to capture browsers back button event and perform your code in it , see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/js-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector

Comment: use sessionstorage to save the state of the button

Comment: browser back button event capture not works,And also the session storage not works,because page is not reloading when back button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea from my side
set all the selections in session variables so that we can remember all the settings 
and it will be easy to get back all the times

Comment: When back button is clicked the page is loading from the browser cache.So session variables didn't get values in it.If i refresh its works fine