# Catch close event when user press back button on instagram/facebook

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvZEu.jpg)I can't catch any close event in my site when user come from Facebook / Instagram ads (mobile) and press on the app back button (on the top corner).

I already tried to use "pagehide", "beforeunload" and "visibilitychange".
None of them works.

### Edit:

I added a picture, in the picture I show the back button od the facebook messenger app (same as in case of entering to ads on Facebook and Instagram).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript or jQuery browser back button click detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/javascript-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector)

Comment: @Kobe I tried this and it didn't work.