# Django: window.onpopstate unexpected behavior with Chrome 79

Tags: django, back

**EDIT**

finally I use window.onpopstate event to prevent user go back
it works with Firefox but not with Chrome 79 (and other browsers?)

I have read many posts and official documentation that seems to say that this 'bug' was fixed after Chrome 34... but doesn't seems to be
to be honest, event reading the documentation, I do not really understand this event and the behavior so far...

How can I resolve this?

---

I know this topic has been already discuss but none of solutions resolve my problem.

I have 3 forms that update the same models.
I would like to manage/prevent user going back using back arrow.

I tried using window.location, window.onhashchange = function () {}, flag session variable but nothing works and I am lost

When user click on back arrow from 2nd form to go back to 1st form, I would like either the event is blocked (best), either user is redirected to home page

I notice that click on back arrow on the 2nd form do not call index view, reason why 'flag strategy' do not work

```
@login_required
@permission_required('unblind.can_unblind')
def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AveugleProcedureForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            unblind = form.save()
            # database treatment
            return redirect('unblind:edit', pk = unblind.pk)

    else:
        form = AveugleProcedureForm(request)

    return render(request, 'unblind/index.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
@permission_required('unblind.can_unblind')
def edit(request, pk):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AveugleForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # unblind = form.save()
            # database treatment
            unblind = Aveugle.objects.get(unb_ide = pk)
            unblind.unb_pro = form.cleaned_data['unb_pro']
            unblind.unb_nom_dem = form.cleaned_data['unb_nom_dem']
            unblind.unb_nom_rea = form.cleaned_data['unb_nom_rea']
            unblind.unb_dat = form.cleaned_data['unb_dat']
            unblind.pat = form.cleaned_data['pat']
            unblind.unb_num = form.cleaned_data['unb_num']
            unblind.unb_mot = form.cleaned_data['unb_mot']
            unblind.save()

            # contrôler le couple numéro patient/boite de médicament

            # récupération du traitement
            treatment = Medicament.objects.get(med_num = unblind.unb_num).med_dru

            # envoie d'un email de confirmation
            if treatment == 1:
                unblind_treatment = _('ASPIRIN')
            else:
                unblind_treatment = _('PLACEBO')

            email(unblind.pat,unblind.unb_num,unblind_treatment,unblind.unb_mot)

            return redirect('unblind:result', pk = unblind.pk)

    else:
        form = AveugleForm(request)

    return render(request, 'unblind/edit.html', {'form': form,'pk': pk})

@login_required
@permission_required('unblind.can_unblind')
def result(request, pk):
    # Récupération de l'enregistrement
    unblind = Aveugle.objects.get(unb_ide = pk)

    treatment = Medicament.objects.get(med_num = unblind.unb_num).med_dru
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AveugleResultForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # database treatment
            unblind.unb_rec = form.cleaned_data['unb_rec']
            # unblind.unb_com = form.cleaned_data['unb_com']
            unblind.unb_log_dat = datetime.now()
            unblind.unb_log = request.user.username
            unblind.unb_log_sit = request.session['selected_site']
            unblind.save()

            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = AveugleResultForm(request)

    return render(request, 'unblind/result.html', {'form': form,'unblind':unblind,'treatment':treatment})
```

Comment: try this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/javascript-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector) ```     $(document).ready( function () {

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/javascript-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector
        // Ashik Jyothi
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            alert("clicked back button");
        }; 
        history.pushState({}, '');
      });``` but do not work on chrome

Comment: work on firefox

Comment: UP ! someone can help?